# file_get_contents between two docker containers

Tags: php, docker, file-get-contents

**Situation:**

*Docker container1:* Wordpress used as REST api.

*Docker container2:* Simple php server running a single page application. (vue.js)

**Problem:**

I'm not able to use file_get_contents in container2 to retrieve the json from container1.

Using `file_get_contents('http://url.of.container1/wp-json');` causes the following server error:

`[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting`

Which seems like an infinity loop. Doing the exact same request to a non docker container works fine and returns the json. `allow_url_fopen` is on.

All tips are greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

PROJECTNAME:
  build: .
  expose:
    - 80
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=PROJECTNAME.development
  volumes: 
    - ./app/dest:/var/www/html

wordpress_PROJECTNAME:
  image: wordpress
  external_links:
    - db:mysql
  expose:
    - 80
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.PROJECTNAME.development
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=PROJECTNAME
    - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=root
  volumes: 
    - ./public:/var/www/html
    # - ./custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini

networks:

default:
  external:
    name: nginx-proxy
```

DockerFile for the first container:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Can you please share your docker compose file?

Comment: @zstate docker-compose file has been added. I have a nginx reverse proxy setup for my local `.development` domains

Comment: I wonder, did you find a solution for this?